# Equivalent of Array.some and Array.every in Haskell?

Tags: javascript, haskell, functional-programming

Something like this type `[(a->b)] -> a -> [b]` . of course I can code it, but I want to have the correct functional name for it.

Here is the situation:

I'm new to functional programming , and I'm currently using JavaScript for it.

I have an array of predicate functions:

```js
 //predicate :: string -> a -> boolean

 let arr = [ predicate(foo), predicate(bar), predicate(baz) ]
```

I want to apply them to a `value`, and get back an array of results :

```js
 let res = [ arr[0](value), arr[1](value), arr[2](value) ]
 // res = [ true ,false, true]
```

And at the end i want to chain the array using `Any.concat` or `All.concat`

```js
 final_result = Any(res[0]).concat(Any(res[1])).concat(Any(res[2])).valueOf()
 // final_result = true | false
```

Thank you.

Comment: I'm not a Javascript expert, but I am a Haskell expert. What does `Any(true)` do?

Comment: @DanielWagner sorry my bad ,not part of javascript . it's the Monoid Any implemented in js . https://crocks.dev/docs/monoids/Any.html .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haskell is not category theory. Haskell is Haskell.

Another way to write the functions would be:

```
import Data.Monoid (Any(..), All (..))
import Data.Coerce

any' :: [a -> Bool] -> a -> Bool
any' = fmap getAny . foldMap (fmap Any)
-- alternatively
any' = fmap getAny . foldMap coerce
```

and

```
all' :: [a -> Bool] -> a -> Bool
all' = fmap getAll . foldMap (fmap All)
-- alternatively
all' = fmap getAll . foldMap coerce
```

Using [`foldMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:foldMap), and also optionally [`coerce`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Coerce.html#v:coerce) to avoid having to write `fmap Any` or `fmap All`, which can be inferred from type information elsewhere.

This answer depends of the fact that a function ending on a monoid is itself a monoid:

> Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b)

Because [`Any`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Any) and [`All`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:All) have `Monoid` instances, `a -> Any` and `a -> All` will also have [`Monoid`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Monoid) instances.

`mempty :: a -> Any` is a function that ignores its input and returns `mempty :: Any`, which is `Any False`, the neutral element of the "or" operation. Similarly for `a -> All`.

`mappend :: (a -> Any) -> (a -> Any) -> a -> Any` takes two functions, and returns a new function that feeds its own input to each of the previous functions and performs a `mappend` of the resulting `Any`s. Similarly for `a -> All`.

The `foldMap` function combines the action of mapping over some list—producing values that are instances of `Monoid`—with the action of `mappend`ing all the resulting values. In our case we are simply wrapping the "tip" of the functions into `Any`/`All` to be able to `mappend` the functions. Then—somewhat annoyingly—we have to undo the wrapping.

Comment: Your imports are wrong: you want to import `Any(..)`, or else you won't be able to access the Any constructor. Also I am not really a fan of using `(fmap Any)` as a synonym for `(. Any)` - implicit use of the function functor is often pretty confusing.

Comment: @amalloy Thanks, corrected. I agree that using the function `Functor`/`Applicative`/`Monad` is often confusing, but in the particular case of reaching to the "end" of the function to apply some conversion, I prefer it to `(. Any)`. I find operator sections involving `.` difficult to understand. It's also easy to add more `fmap`s to handle functions with more than one parameter.

Comment: I agree with amalloy. `(Any .)` is _clearer_ than `fmap Any`, because it doesn't leave any question about what functor we're dealing with. (The order is important though, `(. Any)` is something different!)

Comment: @danidiaz thank you . i'm very new to all these , so sorry if i'm wrong , but i think you kinda defined a custom `any` or `all` , the accepted answer uses what is already available . i may be wrong though.

Comment: @BabakKarimiAsl Yes. There are preexisting `and` and `all` functions which work directly with bools, and then (independently) there are newtypes `Any` and `All` in `Data.Monoid`. Values of these newtypes are combined using their `Monoid` instances. It's a different style: with the newtypes, the exact and/or operation to perform is *associated with the newtype itself*, which then has a "mash values together" operation given by the `Monoid` instance. Also, `mempty :: All` and `mempty :: Any` will return the neutral elements for the `and` and `or` operations, respectively.

Comment: @BabakKarimiAsl The operation which "mashes things together" is called `mappend` http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#v:mappend The operator `<>` can also be used http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#v:-60--62-

Comment: @danidiaz thank you , can you add `mappend` into your answer ? and can you somehow 
show the usecase of `flip` or `flap` in this situation ? so i can accept your answer ?

Comment: @BabakKarimiAsl I'm not sure we need `flip` here. `all'` receives a list of predicates and the value to which they should be applied. Isn't that enough?

Comment: On `(Any .)` and `fmap Any`, I sometimes wonder if `rmap Any` would be nicer than both in terms of communicating intent, and similarly for the other dot section and `lmap`. (I'm not necessarily suggesting that for this specific question, as it might be too big a detour with `Profunctor` not being in *base* yet.)

Answer (score 2):

In Haskell we have `sequence`, which specializes to:

```hs
sequence :: [a -> b] -> a -> [b]
```

But I wouldn't use it for the code you showed. Instead I would write one of these:

```hs
finalResult = or [predicate x value | x <- arr]
finalResult = any (flip predicate value) arr
```

Comment: I downvoted, because this uses the function Applicative (which is often confusing, and suggests there's something deeper categorically going on than it actually is) without even mentioning it.